# java struts1: forward from action to action with One ActionForm

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, actionform

Like I said  in the title , I have two  actions ( `studentAction`  , `UpdateStudentAction` ) One , action form :  `studentForm` and the struts-config like :

```
<action path="/student"
    type="action.StudentAction"
    name="studentForm"
    scope="request"
    validate="true"
    input="tiles.etudiant"
    parameter="dispatch">       
    <forward name="UpdateStudent"  path="/updateStudent.do" redirect="true" />  
</action>

<action path="/updateStudent"
    type="action.UpdateStudentAction"
    scope="request"
    name="studentForm"
    input="tiles.modifierEtudiant"
    parameter="dispatch">
</action>
```

**First action method to  redirect**

```
public ActionForward onModifier(
        ActionMapping mapping,
        ActionForm form,
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response)
        throws DatabaseFailureException {       
StudentForm studentForm=(StudentForm)form;
return mapping.findForward("UpdateStudent");
```

}

**The Second Action method (recipient) :**

```
public ActionForward onInitialiser(
        ActionMapping mapping,
        ActionForm form,
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response)
        throws DatabaseFailureException {

        StudentForm studentForm=(StudentForm)form;
        //etudiantForm.setIdEtudiantSelectionne("1");
        List listeCriteres=new ArrayList();
        listeCriteres.add(new SearchBean(new Etudiant().HQL_ID_ETUDIANT(), etudiantForm.getIdEtudiantSelectionne()));   etudiantForm.setListeEtudiants(getReferenceDataService().findListBoParCriteres(Etudiant.class, listeCriteres));

        return mapping.getInputForward();   }
```

**Here is the probleme ,  the second action   get  an empty form from the first one **
 how can i  fix this problem ?!

Comment: I do not know if I am right but i  just fixed it  , by  changing the scope var   to  session ,   there is  an other solution  to  do  it properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes one more way is changing the redirect attribute value to false <forward name="UpdateStudent"  path="/updateStudent.do" **redirect="false"** />